# Start and stop Fiddler from command line

Tags: fiddler, fiddlercore, fiddler-dev

I have the following requirement:

I need to start Fiddler from the command line. It will start capturing my traffic immediately. After some time, I want to stop capturing the traffic, but not close Fiddler.

What is the best way to achieve this ? I've explored Fiddler's command-line options, but they will only start Fiddler and not stop it. Also, killing the Fiddler process will not save my session safely. Please help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are several ways to do this. The simplest is to run

`%programfiles(x86)%\fiddler2\execaction.exe stop`

This calls the `execaction` program in the Fiddler install folder, passing it the command `stop`. The `stop` message is sent to Fiddler, whose script handler (click Rules > Customize Rules, scroll to `OnExecAction`) will interpret it as a command to detach as the system proxy.

To reattach the proxy, use `start` as the command. You can see what other commands are available (and add your own) by looking at the `OnExecAction` function.